# Conditional breakpoint when debugging XSLT in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, debugging

I found out that you can debug XSLT in Visual Studio, which is pretty cool, but how do you set a *conditional* breakpoint?

For example, how would I break only if a certain variable is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Does right-clicking on the breakpoint red-circle and selecting "Condition" work for you?